# How to find replication factor of a topic using Java API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am having hard time figuring out how to get replication factor of a topic using Java API.

I have tried AdminClient but haven't had any success.

```
listTopics() - returns the list of topics and #of partitions per topic
describeConfigs() - return other metadata such as retention.ms, cleanup policy etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, getting the replication factor via the Admin API is not very intuitive.

You basically need to count the number of replicas for any partition (assuming there're no reassignments in progress). This is what `TopicCommand` (`kafka-topics.sh`) does: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/TopicCommand.scala#L577-L591

```java
DescribeTopicsResult describeTopics = admin.describeTopics(topics);
Map<String, TopicDescription> descriptions = describeTopics.all().get();

for (Map.Entry<String, TopicDescription> entry : descriptions.entrySet()) {
    TopicDescription td = entry.getValue();
    int replicationFactor = td.partitions().get(0).replicas().size();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + replicationFactor);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that retrieve the number of active replicas?

Comment: What do you mean by "active" replicas? `replicas()` returns you the assignment which effectively defines the replication factor.

Comment: Assume we have a 2 node cluster. A topic with 2 replicas: one is placed on host-x and another on host-y. If host-y would be down then I think td.partitions().get(0).repliacas().size() would return 1 & when host-y would be up then it would return 2.

Comment: No. Even if a broker is down, it's in the replica list. You maybe are confusing it with `isr()`.